# How to convert array to xml and post to third party?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, curl, gravity-forms-plugin

I am having trouble converting an array into xml and then posting it to an third party URL as an xml post.

I believe i am close but i am missing something for it to work.
I am using wordpress and gravity form (I don't think it matters)

Here is what i have up-till now.

```
function post_to_third_party($entry, $form) {

  $post_url = 'https://xxxx.com/home/BorrowerImport.do?CampaignID=xxx';
  $body = array( 'firstname' => $entry['8.3'],      
    'lastname' => $entry['8.6'],
    'dayphone' => $entry['12'],
    'email' => $entry['11']    
  );

  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<application/>');
  $body = array_flip($body);
  array_walk($body, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
  print $xml->asXML();

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $output;

  curl_close($ch); 
}
```

I also tried the following code this seems to work but the var_dump looks like string(201) " $firstname $lastname $dayphone $email " ok

I don't know how to populate the xml tags with the data gathered from the $body array

Here is the code i used for this result

```
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2);
function post_to_third_party($entry, $form) {

$post_url = 'https://xxxx.com/home/BorrowerImport.do?CampaignID=xxx';
$body = array(
    'firstname' =>     $entry['8.3'],      
    'lastname' =>     $entry['8.6'],
    'dayphone' =>   $entry['12'],
    'email' =>  $entry['11']    
    );
$xml = '

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <application>
    <firstname>$firstname</firstname>
    <lastname>$lastname</lastname>
    <dayphone>$dayphone</dayphone>
    <email>$email</email>
    </application>';
var_dump($xml);

$ch = curl_init($url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $output;

    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: var_dump your xml and post it. I'm pretty sure you need to create a loop for your array to generate the XML.

Comment: Also, what's the problem? Your PHP does not create an XML document? The XML document is created but not sent? The XML document is sent but rejected by the other server? One possible problem: you're passing the SimpleXMLElement object to the `curl_setopt` function for the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` argument - do you want to pass the XML string instead?

Comment: this is what i got when i did var_dump($xml);
test(801)735-2222test@gmail.com object(SimpleXMLElement)#310 (3) { ["lastname"]=> string(4) "test" ["dayphone"]=> string(13) "(801)735-2222" ["email"]=> string(14) "test@gmail.com" } Import error

Comment: Its saying import error

Comment: @Kryten all i have been told is to post an xml document to the third party url using http post the xml structure is as follows

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <firstname>Jason</firstname>
  <lastname>Doe</lastname>
</application>

Comment: An XML document is a structured representation of some data. The remote server is expecting that data in a specific form - if you're not sending it the way the server wants it, it's going to complain.  Unfortunately, "import error" is a remarkably unhelpful error message. You're going to have to ask for the XML schema to figure out how they want the data.

Comment: @Kryten I believe XML schema is as follows (I am not too well versed with xml)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <firstname>Jason</firstname>
  <lastname>Doe</lastname> 
</application>

Comment: @MattTheNinja what do you mean by a loop? should i use array_walk_recursive ?

Comment: The XML schema is the detailed specification of values & types permitted. What you have there is an example of a document. You can probably make this work if you copy the form of your example. For instance, I notice in your example that there are only `firstname` and `lastname` fields - maybe the server doesn't like the `dayphone` and `email` fields.

Comment: @Kryten I just shorten the example to show you a snippet email and dayphone are valid its in the accepted fields.

Comment: I also used a different code which seems to work but i have no idea how to get the data from $body array to the respective XML tags. See Above

Comment: Your original code seemed to build the XML document just fine. I tried it out at http://ideone.com/1eQYVz.

Comment: @Kryten that's interesting could it be that the example xml says <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and mine is only producing <?xml version="1.0"?> if so then how do i add encoding="UTF-8"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the problem:

The method you are using to build the array before converting to XML is accidentally deleting some of the data.

You start out with something like this:

```
$body = array(
    "firstname" => "Test",
    "lastname" => "Test",
    "dayphone" => "(801)735-2222",
    "email" => "test@gmail.com",
);
```

Then you call `array_flip`, which gives you this:

```
$body = array(
    "Test" => "firstname",
    "Test" => "lastname",
    "(801)735-2222" => "dayphone",
    "test@gmail.com" => "email",
);
```

You now have two "Test" keys in your array. PHP keeps the last one an throws away the first. So your XML document is now missing one of the required keys: "firstname".

The solution is to build your XML document the old fashioned way and stay away from fancy stuff like `array_flip`:

```
foreach($body as $k=$v)
    $xml->addChild($k, $v);
```